# can we use firebase dynamic link for website

Tags: firebase-dynamic-links

Can we use Firebase Dynamic Links as own URL shortener for a website? Will it work in mobile devices. If I build Do Follow link in Shortened URL ([l.andrimo.com/xyz](https://l.andrimo.com/Ux8Y)) is this transfer authority like [goo.gl](https://goo.gl)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase Dynamic Links can be used as a URL shortener for web sites. From the [blog post announcing the turn down of `goo.gl`](https://developers.googleblog.com/2018/03/transitioning-google-url-shortener.html):

> Firebase Dynamic Links are smart URLs that allow you to send existing and potential users to any location within an iOS, Android or **web app**.

Whether Firebase Dynamic Links suits the needs of your use-case, only you can determine.